# Metamask Warning

Tags: metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp

In an effort to improve user privacy, MetaMask will stop exposing user accounts to dapps by default beginning November 2nd, 2018. Dapps should call provider.enable() in order to view and use accounts.

I am getting this warning from metamask. Where should I call provider.enable()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Metamask published an article explaining how to inject web3. you can find how to do it here: https://medium.com/metamask/https-medium-com-metamask-breaking-change-injecting-web3-7722797916a8

The code, in case the link gets broken is:

```
window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
    // Modern dapp browsers...
    if (window.ethereum) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
        try {
            // Request account access if needed
            await ethereum.enable();
            // Acccounts now exposed
            web3.eth.sendTransaction({/* ... */});
        } catch (error) {
            // User denied account access...
        }
    }
    // Legacy dapp browsers...
    else if (window.web3) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        // Acccounts always exposed
        web3.eth.sendTransaction({/* ... */});
    }
    // Non-dapp browsers...
    else {
        console.log('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!');
    }
});
```

Hope this helps